# Adding histogram and 1 std band to residual plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have plotted a graph in python with a subplot of residuals and am trying to find a way to at a histogram plot of the residuals on the end of the histogram plot. I would also like to add a grey band on the residual plot showing 1 standard deviation.

also is there a way to remove the top and right-hand side boarders of the plot.

Here is a copy of the code and the graph I currently have.

```
fig1 = pyplot.figure(figsize =(9.6,7.2))
plt.frame1 =fig1.add_axes((0.2,0.4,.75,.6))
pyplot.errorbar(xval, yval*1000, yerr=yerr*1000, xerr=xerr, marker='x', linestyle='None')

# Axis labels
pyplot.xlabel('Height (m)', fontsize = 12)
pyplot.ylabel('dM/dt (g $s^{-1}$)', fontsize = 12)


# Generate best fit line using model function and best fit parameters, and add to plot
fit_line=model_funct(xval, [a_soln, b_soln])
pyplot.plot(xval, fit_line*1000)

# Set suitable axis limits: you will probably need to change these...
#pyplot.xlim(-1, 61)
#pyplot.ylim(65, 105)
# pyplot.show()


plt.frame2 = fig1.add_axes((0.2,0.2,.75,.2))    #start frame1 at 0.2, 0.4 
plt.xlabel("Height of Water (m)", fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel("Normalised\nResiduals", fontsize = 12)    #\n is used to start a new line
plt.plot(h,normalised_residuals,"x", color = "green")
plt.axhline(0, linewidth=1, linestyle="--", color="black")


plt.savefig("Final Graph.png", dpi = 500)
```

[image: Current graph]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve). Right now the code you provide would not run on a fresh Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming in your code is a bit weird, therefore I only post snippets since it is hard to try it by myself. Sometimes you use `pyplot` and sometimes you use `plt` which should be the same. Also you should name your axis like this `ax = fig1.add_axes((0.2,0.4,.75,.6))`. Then, if you do the plot, you should call it with the axis directly, i.e. use `ax.errorbar()`.

To hide the borders of the axis in the top plot use:

```
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
```

Adding an error band in the bottom plot is pretty easy to do. Just calculate the mean and standard deviation using `np.mean()` and `np.std()`. Afterwards, call

```
plt.fill_between(h, y1=np.mean(normalised_residuals) - np.std(normalised_residuals), 
                 y2=np.mean(normalised_residuals) + np.std(normalised_residuals),
                 color='gray', alpha=.5)
```

and change the color and alpha however you want it to be.

For the histogram projection you just add another axis like you've done it two times before (let's assume it is called `ax`) and call

```
ax.hist(normalised_residuals, bins=8, orientation="horizontal")
```

Here, bins has to be set to a small value probably since you don't have that many data points.